# Generate map from string array

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to store some server names in a map based on some predefined logic.

For example if the names are:

```
"temp-a-name1", "temp-a-name2", "temp-b-name1", "temp-b-name2"
```

They'll be stored in a map as:

```
{
  a: [
    "temp-a-name1",
    "temp-a-name2"
  ],
  b: [
    "temp-b-name1",
    "temp-b-name2"
  ]
}
```

The first letter between the two "-" will always be the key

I'm not too familiar with javascript so I've done this the naive way but I was wondering if there's a better, more javascripty way to do this.

```
const servers = ["temp-a-name1", "temp-a-name2", "temp-b-name1", "temp-b-name2"];

let map = {};
let key;
for (const server of servers) {
  key = server.charAt(server.indexOf("-") + 1);
  if (key in map) {
    map[key].push(server);
  } else {
    map[key] = [server];
  }
}
```

Comment: Stick with your version. IMO code is readable and easy to understand, so there is no need for refactoring. BTW, such questions are better suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `reduce()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let servers = ["temp-a-name1", "temp-a-name2", "temp-b-name1", "temp-b-name2"];

let map = servers.reduce((acc, server) => {
  let key = server.charAt(server.indexOf("-") + 1);

  if (acc[key])
    acc[key].push(server);
  else
    acc[key] = [server];
    
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(map)
```

Comment: `reduce()` is not an ES6 feature

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const servers = ["temp-a-name1", "temp-a-name2", "temp-b-name1", "temp-b-name2"];
const result = servers.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
    ...acc,
  [cur.split('-')[1]]: (acc[cur.split('-')[1]] || []).concat([cur]),
}), {})
console.log(result);
```

I think this counts as "javascripty"

Answer (score 1):

I would use reduce. A naive way of getting the key could be `.split('-')[1]`.

```js
const names = ['temp-a-name1', 'temp-a-name2', 'temp-b-name1', 'temp-b-name2'];
const map = names.reduce((map, name) => {
  const key = name.split('-')[1];
  const namesWithKey = map[key] || [];

  return { ...map, [key]: [...namesWithKey, name] };
}, {});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure something like this:

```js
const servers = ["temp-a-name1", "temp-a-name2", "temp-b-name1", "temp-b-name2"];

const map = new Map();

servers.forEach(item => {
  const key = item.split('-')[1];
  const value = map.get(key) || [];
  value.push(item);
  
  map.set(key, value);
});

// CONSOLE LOG
for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```